# Opening a URL that requires Basic HTTP Authentication Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, http

I have a page that is protected by basic http authentication ie the user is prompted for a username and password as shown below:

[screenshot of browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvNP4.jpg)

I would like to bypass this prompt by providing the username and password via javascript. This was simple enough when The following was allowed:

http://username:password@localhost:8042/

Unfortunately browsers no longer allow providing the username:password in the URL. So how would I do the following steps:

1) authenticate with server with username:password 2) open the URL in browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XMLHttpRequest and provide username and password as last arguments

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('get', url, async, 'username', 'password')
xhr.send()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open

You could also open the page protected by http auth in a new tab like this :

```
window.open('http://username:password@localhost:8042')
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. could you provide a full working code sample?

Comment: The code is already fully working. What is your issue with it?